# What's the preferred workflow for deploying coffescript?

Tags: javascript, deployment, coffeescript

Should I store `.coffee` files in git and compile them server-side with some git hooks, or should I store both `.coffee` and `.js` files in SCM and just ignore coffee at the server?

Are there any disadvantages to storing compiled .js files except extra SCM space usage? I'd rather not have to install node, npm and coffee on each server.

Comment: Why is it an issue for you to install node and coffeescript on the server?

Comment: This is a bit of a subjective question, because deployment systems vary so much, and prescribing a "preferred workflow" would require pretty intimate knowledge of your setup. That said, checking compiled JS files into source control just because it's convenient is a sign that your deployment system can be greatly improved.

Comment: Your choice of server here is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workflows that I've seen are for Rails and Node. My current process is based on them and looks like:

1. Keep .coffee files in `/assets/src/coffee`
2. Keep compiled .js files in `/assets/js` and reference them as `/js/foo.js`
3. Keep .js files that are external to your app (e.g. a graphing utility) in `/assets/lib`
4. Exclude `/assets/js` from your source control
5. Set up your middleware to compile coffeescript files on the fly if they aren't already compiled. `connect-coffee-script` was the one I liked best.

The process in Rails is pretty similar, to the best of my recollection.

> Are there any disadvantages to storing compiled .js files except extra SCM space usage? I'd rather not have to install node, npm and coffee on each server.

I see no good reason to put compiled js into source -- your middleware should handle turning coffee into js. I also see no disadvantage to installing coffee on your server -- you should be doing an npm update as part of your build process and that should take care of it.

Here's the code for setting it up:

```
var app = express();
  ...
srcFolder = path.join(__dirname, 'assets', 'src', 'coffee');
publicFolder = path.join(__dirname, 'assets');


app.configure(function () {
  ...
app.use(require('connect-coffee-script')({
    src:srcFolder, dest:path.join(publicFolder, 'js'), force:true
}));
```

It's also important to note that I had some issues getting this going on Windows 7; node's file watchers seem to have some issues there. So I have to have a command window with this running while developing: `coffee -o ./assets/js  -wc ./assets/src/coffee`.